# Do I need to use a comma between two adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, commas

```
You can also contact me to customize your template, or create a new unique one.
```

Do I need to put a comma between the **new** and **unique** adjectives in this sentence?  In my native language (if I am not mistaken) we don't put a comma if the adjectives are of a different type. Not sure about English though, and if it's the case here anyway. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the intended meaning. With stacked, or layered,  modification (no comma), "one, i.e. template"" is first modified by "unique" to give "unique template", and this in turn is modified by "new" to give "new unique template", i.e. "template that is new by the standards applicable to unique ones". By contrast, with coordinated modification (with a comma), "one" is modified by a coordination of adjectives giving the meaning "template that is both unique and new".

Comment: See [Comma between adjectives ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227713/comma-between-adjectives-in-title-of-thesis/227720#227720).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a comma is a classic case of "depends!"

Have a look at [this blog entry](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives) from grammar girl.

> The comma rule comes down to the difference between two kinds of adjectives: coordinate adjectives and cumulative adjectives.
>
> ...
>
> Just remember that if you can reverse your two adjectives or can place an “and” between them, you need a comma.

So in this case, use a comma.

Comment: I object a bit. The Oxford/serial comma is a debated practice, and while it can clarify meaning, rephrasing or reordering a sentence is also a completely valid use-case.

The sentence above is a case of "implied information". Say, you rephrase it to: "You can also contact me to customize or create a new unique template." Where [customize] implies an existing template, and the [create] has to carry the new one. Or simply put "an existing" before the or - then of course, i'd argue you'd need a comma. With the Oxford comma, you clarify the subject of the adjective, but it is Not a requirement.

Comment: @Sakatox The Oxford comma is an optional comma before the word "and" at the end of a list (often nouns), not sequential adjectival modifiers which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: It's the same thing - an adjective list. A sequence is a list, the difference is the separator between the elements.

Comment: @Sakatox I disagree. The Oxford comma is about punctuation; it is always optional, a matter of personal preference, whereas the comma we're talking about here may be obligatory for the meaning of the phrase. Additionally, the Oxford comma is used before the word "and" at the end of a list of three or more items.

Comment: There's no rule to not do a two element list of: this, and that, using the Oxford comma. I just did it. I didn't debate the Oxford comma's usage, i debated the accepted answer - as in, you're missing my point.

Comment: @Sakatox You used the term "Oxford comma" in your message to Helmar to "object a bit" about his answer, but it really is irrelevant to the OP's question. The Oxford comma is primarily about punctuation/ the clarification of a list, an optional item that some prefer to use, while others do not. We're talking here about one or more commas in a list of _pre-modifying adjectives_ that may be obligatory to disambiguate the **modification** in a noun phrase. An example of the Oxford comma would be: "I like London, Liverpool, and Edinburgh" (note the three items and the optional comma before "and".)

Comment: @Sakatox - In your two element list, you use two commas, making the 2nd element adverbial.  If you left out the 2nd comma, you would create a garden-path fault.